# Error while installing uWSGI on mac

Tags: django, uwsgi

I need uWSGI for running a django project. So when i'm trying to install uWSGI, its giving me an error saying "Exception: you need a C compiler to build uWSGI". But mac comes with gcc compiler.

I've downloaded uWSGI from "http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/WikiStart#Getit" and tried to install by the command "python setup.py install"

This is the error i got while installing uWSGI

```
running install
using profile: buildconf/default.ini
detected include path: ['/usr/local/include', '/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple
darwin11/4.2.1/include', '/usr/include', '/System/Library/Frameworks', '/Library/Frameworks']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 98, in <module>
    distclass=uWSGIDistribution,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py",
line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py",
line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py",
line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 61, in run
    conf = uc.uConf(get_profile())
  File "/Users/jay/Downloads/Softwares/Work/uwsgi-1.2.4/uwsgiconfig.py", line 340, in __init__
    raise Exception("you need a C compiler to build uWSGI")
Exception: you need a C compiler to build uWSGI
```

Comment: So what happens when you type `gcc` from the command line?

Comment: It says "i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: no input files" when i type gcc in terminal

Comment: I would guess you have to install the developer tools, namely XCode. When you install XCode you can select different packages. There you'll have to select "UNIX development support". After that, try installing again.

Comment: I already have xcode version 4.2.1

Answer (score 40):

gcc already installed, just export CC=gcc will be ok.

Comment: thanks, but how to export CC=gcc, i tried "export CC=gcc" in the terminal. but it did not work out

Comment: Late to the game, but: $ export CC=gcc && pip install -r requirements.txt

Comment: This worked for me. I had to do this for fish: "set -x CC gcc"

Answer (score 18):

distutils is probably returning something like "gcc-4.2" instead of plain old "gcc".

With sudo, etc., you probably want to do something like this:

```
sudo CC=gcc pip install uwsgi
```

Answer (score 7):

Install CommandLine Tools

```
$xcode-select --install
```

Then run

```
$pip install uwsgi
```

Answer (score 0):

first install gcc compiler

```
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Xcode in your mac than select command line tool in Xcode preferences. It works for me by doing pip install uwsgi

Answer (score 0):

## Use pip with `sudo`

sometimes pip packages are not installed or python is not able to create runnable files for virtualenv just because it doesn't have enough permissions. Since it is not showing permission error, it is taking time to resolve it. You can use following command to install it.

`sudo python -m pip install uwsgi`
or
`sudo pip install uwsgi`

Answer (score 0):

Note for mac's that this could actually be because xcode requires you to accept the license agreement from the command line before it lets you run `gcc`

Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please run “sudo xcodebuild -license” and then retry this command.