# Installing UWSGI on OSX in virtualenv

Tags: python, macos, uwsgi

So I'm trying to setup a project on my new work computer and I'm running into issues I never had on my personal computer. I'm trying to pip install from the requirements.txt file. I've got GCC, Xcode, command line tools, python, pip all installed but I still get the following when running `pip install -r requirements.txt` from within the env:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Django==1.9.7 in ./env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): psycopg2==2.6.1 in ./env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Pillow==3.1.1 in ./env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django-bootstrap3==5.4.0 in ./env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): easy-thumbnails==2.2 in ./env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lxml==3.4.4 in ./env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cssselect==0.9.1 in ./env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests==2.8.0 in ./env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django-taggit==0.18.1 in ./env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django-storages==1.1.8 in ./env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): boto==2.39.0 in ./env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django-smtp-ssl==1.0 in ./env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Wand==0.4.1 in ./env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz==2015.7 in ./env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 14))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): newrelic in ./env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 15))
Collecting uwsgi==2.0.12 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
  Using cached uwsgi-2.0.12.tar.gz
Collecting django-pipeline==1.6.8 (from -r requirements.txt (line 17))
  Using cached django_pipeline-1.6.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting django-pipeline-compass-rubygem==0.1.9 (from -r requirements.txt (line 18))
Collecting jsmin==2.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 19))
Collecting django-admin-sortable==2.0.18 (from -r requirements.txt (line 20))
Collecting feedparser==5.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 21))
Collecting beautifulsoup4==4.5.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 22))
  Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.5.1-py2-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: uwsgi
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for uwsgi ... error
Complete output from command /Users/nathomer/Documents/code/meural/myMeural/env/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/w_/jqnvb03x6bs9334qbx39d4y80000gn/T/pip-build-kcaA1Y/uwsgi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /var/folders/w_/jqnvb03x6bs9334qbx39d4y80000gn/T/tmp_EJI_qpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib
  copying uwsgidecorators.py -> build/lib
  installing to build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/wheel
  running install
  using profile: buildconf/default.ini
  detected include path: ['/usr/local/include', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.0.0/include', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include', '/usr/include', '/System/Library/Frameworks', '/Library/Frameworks']
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/private/var/folders/w_/jqnvb03x6bs9334qbx39d4y80000gn/T/pip-build-kcaA1Y/uwsgi/setup.py", line 109, in <module>
  distclass=uWSGIDistribution,
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
  dist.run_commands()
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
  self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
  cmd_obj.run()
    File "/Users/nathomer/Documents/code/meural/myMeural/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 235, in run
  self.run_command('install')
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
  self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
  cmd_obj.run()
    File "/private/var/folders/w_/jqnvb03x6bs9334qbx39d4y80000gn/T/pip-build-kcaA1Y/uwsgi/setup.py", line 71, in run
  conf = uc.uConf(get_profile())
    File "uwsgiconfig.py", line 700, in __init__
      raise Exception("you need a C compiler to build uWSGI")
  Exception: you need a C compiler to build uWSGI

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for uwsgi
  Running setup.py clean for uwsgi
Failed to build uwsgi
Installing collected packages: uwsgi, django-pipeline, django-pipeline-compass-rubygem, jsmin, django-admin-sortable, feedparser, beautifulsoup4
  Running setup.py install for uwsgi ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/nathomer/Documents/code/meural/myMeural/env/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/w_/jqnvb03x6bs9334qbx39d4y80000gn/T/pip-build-kcaA1Y/uwsgi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/w_/jqnvb03x6bs9334qbx39d4y80000gn/T/pip-obbWpw-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/nathomer/Documents/code/meural/myMeural/env/bin/../include/site/python2.7/uwsgi:
    running install
    using profile: buildconf/default.ini
    detected include path: ['/usr/local/include', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.0.0/include', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include', '/usr/include', '/System/Library/Frameworks', '/Library/Frameworks']
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/w_/jqnvb03x6bs9334qbx39d4y80000gn/T/pip-build-kcaA1Y/uwsgi/setup.py", line 109, in <module>
    distclass=uWSGIDistribution,
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
      File "/private/var/folders/w_/jqnvb03x6bs9334qbx39d4y80000gn/T/pip-build-kcaA1Y/uwsgi/setup.py", line 71, in run
    conf = uc.uConf(get_profile())
      File "uwsgiconfig.py", line 700, in __init__
        raise Exception("you need a C compiler to build uWSGI")
    Exception: you need a C compiler to build uWSGI

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/nathomer/Documents/code/meural/myMeural/env/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/w_/jqnvb03x6bs9334qbx39d4y80000gn/T/pip-build-kcaA1Y/uwsgi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/w_/jqnvb03x6bs9334qbx39d4y80000gn/T/pip-obbWpw-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/nathomer/Documents/code/meural/myMeural/env/bin/../include/site/python2.7/uwsgi" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/w_/jqnvb03x6bs9334qbx39d4y80000gn/T/pip-build-kcaA1Y/uwsgi/
```

What's the deal? What am I missing?

Comment: "you need a C compiler to build uWSGI" looks like i can not be found.

Comment: I figured as much; which is why I installed GCC. Which one should I install?

Comment: Just make sure it is in your `PATH` and can be called anywhere as `gcc`.

Comment: Just assuming I have no idea what I'm doing, what would that actually look like as a full line in my .bash_profile?

Answer (score 0):

You should already have a C compiler installed. Try this:

```
export CC=gcc && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669594/error-while-installing-uwsgi-on-mac)

Comment: That only leads to another, even longer set of errors, unfortunately (so long that I believe I need to open a new question to post all the characters if I were to edit this one).

Answer (score 0):

it is unclear which XCode is used, i ran into similar problems with XCode 8,
and solved it by installing XCode7 into /Applications
and then

`sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode7.app/Contents/Developer/`

`pip install uwsgi`went smoothly ...